# CString IsEmpty keeps returning true

Tags: c-strings, is-empty

For some reason CString IsEmpty keeps returning true even though the CString is obviously not empty.

```
CString temp = "Hello";
if (temp.IsEmpty)
  AfxMessageBox("temp is empty");
else
  AfxMessageBox("temp is not empty");
```

Any reason why this is the case?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps:

```
if(temp.IsEmpty())
```

not

```
if(temp.IsEmpty)
```

Answer (score 0):

Iam not totally sure but try this:

```
CString temp( "Hello" );
```

I found in this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa314317%28v=vs.60%29.aspx 
Look at the end, it says

```
CString city = "Philadelphia"; // NOT the assignment operator
```

Hope this helps!:)